# how to read items in listbox to integer

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, parsing, listbox

I have a listbox but the items is string and when i use this code. it cannot determine what is the highest because it is a string; but the code is working.

I have a 1 1 1 in my listbox but the error said

> Additional information:  Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid.

this is my code

```
    Dim max As Integer = 0
    Dim result = ""

    For Each s As Integer In GARAGE.ListBox5.Items
        If max < s Then
            max = s
            result = s
        End If
        GARAGE.Label19.Text = result
    Next
```

Comment: You seem to have an empty string (`""`) in your ListBox, which can't be converted to an `Integer`.

Comment: Turn on Option Strict.  ListBox items do not contain integers...ever

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the ListItem Value or Text to Integer as in the following example

```
Dim max as Integer = 0
For Each i As ListItem In GARAGE.ListBox5.Items
    Dim s As Integer = 0

    'If you are sure there are all numerics use following statement
    s = Int32.Parse(i.Text)

    'in case there are non numeric values, even blanks, use following statement
    'Int32.TryParse(i.Text, s)
    If max < s Then
        max = s
    End If
Next
GARAGE.Label19.Text = max.ToString()
```

Comment: That won't make any difference in this case

Comment: You must ensure that all the values in the list are numeric, in case you have any non-numeric value then to avoid any exception you should use `Int32.TryParse(i.Text, out s)` instead

Answer (score 0):

Your issue seems to be that one of the values in your ListBox is an Empty String which cannot be parsed into a numeric value.

You should probably do something more like this, so that it either throws an exception or ignores non-numeric values:

```
    Dim maxValue As Integer = 0
    For Each listBoxItem As Object In ListBox1.Items
        Dim i As Integer
        If Integer.TryParse(listBoxItem.ToString, i) Then
            If i > maxValue Then maxValue = i
        Else
            'ignore any values that are not-numeric
            'possibly throw an exception if this happens?
        End If
    Next
    MessageBox.Show("The highest value is " & maxValue.ToString)
```

Comment: Thank you sir :) its now ok :)